# How to make a NSTableView inside NSAlert's accessory view with Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to run a Swift script where I want a simple NSAlert to contain a
`NSTableView` so far I could not quite make it work:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import AppKit
import Foundation

let app = NSApplication.shared
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular) // Magic to accept keyboard input and be docked!

class TableViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

    var initialized = false
    let scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: 200, height: 500))
    let tableView = NSTableView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 4, width: 200, height: 500))

    override func loadView() {
        print("Load view")
        self.view = NSView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("Didweload")
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayout() {
        print("viewDidLayout")

        if !initialized {
            initialized = true
            setupView()
            setupTableView()
        }
    }

    func setupView() {
        print("setupView")
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200))
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        print("setupTableView")
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        // self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 23))
        // self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        // self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        tableView.frame = scrollView.bounds
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.headerView = nil
        scrollView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        scrollView.drawsBackground = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        tableView.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearance.Name.vibrantDark)

        let col = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "col"))
        col.minWidth = 200
        tableView.addTableColumn(col)

        scrollView.documentView = tableView
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = false
        scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        print("tableView")

        let text = NSTextField()
        text.stringValue = "Hello World"
        let cell = NSTableCellView()
        cell.addSubview(text)
        text.drawsBackground = false
        text.isBordered = false
        text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: text, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        // cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: text, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 13))
        // cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: text, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: -13))
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
        print("tableView")

        let rowView = NSTableRowView()
        rowView.isEmphasized = false
        return rowView
    }

}

func runOptionsDialog(args: [String]) {
    let title = args[0]
    let text = args[1]
    let okButton = args[2]
    let cancelButton = args[3]

    let a = NSAlert()
    a.messageText = title
    a.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.warning
    a.informativeText = text
    a.addButton(withTitle: okButton)
    a.addButton(withTitle: cancelButton)

    let con = TableViewController()
    con.tableView.reloadData()
    a.accessoryView = con.view

    app.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    a.runModal()
}

runOptionsDialog(args:["title", "whast", "ok", "cancel"])
```

I run this with `swift table.swift`.

[image: Output]

Comment: Is `"tableView"` logged? What is the frame size of `text`? What happens if you uncomment the constraints between `text` and `cell`?

Comment: There is no difference actually, but when I assign `a.accessoryView = con.view`
then the following is logged:
Load view
Didweload
viewDidLayout
setupView
setupTableView
viewDidLayout
viewDidLayout

But there is no table view showing up... hm...

Comment: Hint: `NSView()` and `NSTextField()` create a view with frame `(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))`.